# How to learn facebook post id and show comments of that share on my own page?

Tags: facebook, post, comments

I want to show comments of shared links on my web page via PHP. But i couldn't find to get 113963072025344 id from fql or open graph.

Main story is : Users can share some links from my web page and it looks like in below link.
https://www.facebook.com/ssafak/posts/113963072025344

After this share some others can write comments on that share. Problem is starting at this point. Members sharing lins via facebook url from my web page. (http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://xxxxxx.xxx/?share=11111111111111) with open-graph meta tags. After this share I have to learn 113963072025344 (exact facebook post link) id with some kind of fql or something like that. But i could't find a way. Besides how can I show that comments like comments under developers page if I find a post id?

Notice: I have got my api key or necessary facebook things for my web page.

If you can share any other suggestions or solutions with me I would be glad.

Comment: Use the Feed dialog for posting, it returns the post id (not sure if only when invoked via `FB.ui` out of the JS SDK; or also when using the direct URL version). Although without a user access token with `read_stream` permission, you will only be able to read that post from the API if it is public.